# Logo in the Res folders doesn't get updated on new runs for Android

Tags: android, resources, android-emulator, android-image, android-icons

I'm encountering a problem which i cant find an answer online or in stackoverflow. It should be pretty simple but i cant solve it.

I've recently created a new bunch of launch icons which i've placed in the different folders of the RES directory and I tried to run my emulator but it doesn't get updated. It still runs the old images which I've replaced.

Is it because I forgot to clear any caches (is there is any in android sdk ?? ) or whats happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the app from your Android device/emulator, and then run from Eclipse.

This will ensure a fresh install of the app on your Android device/emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Eclipse-->Project-->Clean

Then clean your project..

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your default image icon with your new icon, then right click on RES folder, and choose refresh.